# Error when trying to use UISlider to change rate in Swift audio app

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I am getting an error that reads Thread 1: EX_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0). Specifically, this line, `player.rate = sliderValue.value` is being flagged.

```
//  RecorderViewController.swift

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

/**
Uses AVAudioRecorder to record a sound file and an AVAudioPlayer to play it back.
*/
class RecorderViewController: UIViewController {

var recorder: AVAudioRecorder!

var player:AVAudioPlayer!

@IBOutlet var recordButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var stopButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var playButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var statusLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var sliderValue: UISlider!

var meterTimer:NSTimer!

var soundFileURL:NSURL!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    stopButton.enabled = false
    playButton.enabled = false
    setSessionPlayback()
    askForNotifications()
    checkHeadphones()
}

func updateAudioMeter(timer:NSTimer) {

    if recorder.recording {
        let min = Int(recorder.currentTime / 60)
        let sec = Int(recorder.currentTime % 60)
        let s = String(format: "%02d:%02d", min, sec)
        statusLabel.text = s
        recorder.updateMeters()
        // if you want to draw some graphics...
        //var apc0 = recorder.averagePowerForChannel(0)
        //var peak0 = recorder.peakPowerForChannel(0)
    }
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    recorder = nil
    player = nil
}

@IBAction func removeAll(sender: AnyObject) {
    deleteAllRecordings()
}

@IBAction func record(sender: UIButton) {

    if player != nil && player.playing {
        player.stop()
    }

    if recorder == nil {
        print("recording. recorder nil")
        recordButton.setTitle("Pause", forState:.Normal)
        playButton.enabled = false
        stopButton.enabled = true
        recordWithPermission(true)
        return
    }

    if recorder != nil && recorder.recording {
        print("pausing")
        recorder.pause()
        recordButton.setTitle("Continue", forState:.Normal)

    } else {
        print("recording")
        recordButton.setTitle("Pause", forState:.Normal)
        playButton.enabled = false
        stopButton.enabled = true
        //            recorder.record()
        recordWithPermission(false)
    }
}


@IBAction func stop(sender: UIButton) {
    print("stop")

    recorder?.stop()
    player?.stop()

    meterTimer.invalidate()

    recordButton.setTitle("Record", forState:.Normal)
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try session.setActive(false)
        playButton.enabled = true
        stopButton.enabled = false
        recordButton.enabled = true
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("could not make session inactive")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    //recorder = nil
}

@IBAction func play(sender: UIButton) {
    setSessionPlayback()
    play()
}

func play() {

    var url:NSURL?
    if self.recorder != nil {
        url = self.recorder.url
    } else {
        url = self.soundFileURL!
    }
    print("playing \(url)")

    do {
        self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url!)
        stopButton.enabled = true
        player.enableRate = true
        player.delegate = self
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.volume = 1.0
        player.play()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        self.player = nil
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}


@IBAction func slideChange(sender: AnyObject) {
    player.rate = sliderValue.value
}

func setupRecorder() {
    let format = NSDateFormatter()
    format.dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"
    let currentFileName = "recording-\(format.stringFromDate(NSDate())).m4a"
    print(currentFileName)

    let documentsDirectory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
     self.soundFileURL = documentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(currentFileName)

    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(soundFileURL.absoluteString) {
        // probably won't happen. want to do something about it?
        print("soundfile \(soundFileURL.absoluteString) exists")
    }

    let recordSettings:[String : AnyObject] = [
        AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(unsignedInt:kAudioFormatAppleLossless),
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue,
        AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
        AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0
    ]

    do {
        recorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: soundFileURL, settings: recordSettings)
        recorder.delegate = self
        recorder.meteringEnabled = true
        recorder.prepareToRecord() // creates/overwrites the file at soundFileURL
    } catch let error as NSError {
        recorder = nil
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}

func recordWithPermission(setup:Bool) {
    let session:AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    // ios 8 and later
    if (session.respondsToSelector("requestRecordPermission:")) {
           AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({(granted: Bool)-> Void in
            if granted {
                print("Permission to record granted")
                self.setSessionPlayAndRecord()
                if setup {
                    self.setupRecorder()
                }
                self.recorder.record()
                self.meterTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1,
                    target:self,
                    selector:"updateAudioMeter:",
                    userInfo:nil,
                    repeats:true)
            } else {
                print("Permission to record not granted")
            }
        })
    } else {
        print("requestRecordPermission unrecognized")
    }
}

func setSessionPlayback() {
    let session:AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("could not set session category")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    do {
        try session.setActive(true)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("could not make session active")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func setSessionPlayAndRecord() {
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("could not set session category")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    do {
        try session.setActive(true)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("could not make session active")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func deleteAllRecordings() {
    let docsDir =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    do {
        let files = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(docsDir)
        var recordings = files.filter( { (name: String) -> Bool in
            return name.hasSuffix("m4a")
        })
        for var i = 0; i < recordings.count; i++ {
            let path = docsDir + "/" + recordings[i]

            print("removing \(path)")
            do {
                try fileManager.removeItemAtPath(path)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                NSLog("could not remove \(path)")
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("could not get contents of directory at \(docsDir)")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}

func askForNotifications() {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector:"background:",
        name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification,
        object:nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector:"foreground:",
        name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification,
        object:nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector:"routeChange:",
        name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification,
        object:nil)
}

func background(notification:NSNotification) {
    print("background")
}

func foreground(notification:NSNotification) {
    print("foreground")
}


func routeChange(notification:NSNotification) {
    print("routeChange \(notification.userInfo)")

    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        //print("userInfo \(userInfo)")
        if let reason = userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as? UInt {
            //print("reason \(reason)")
            switch AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason(rawValue: reason)! {
            case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.NewDeviceAvailable:
                print("NewDeviceAvailable")
                print("did you plug in headphones?")
                checkHeadphones()
            case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.OldDeviceUnavailable:
                print("OldDeviceUnavailable")
                print("did you unplug headphones?")
                checkHeadphones()
            case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.CategoryChange:
                print("CategoryChange")
            case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.Override:
                print("Override")
            case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.WakeFromSleep:
                print("WakeFromSleep")
            case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.Unknown:
                print("Unknown")
            case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.NoSuitableRouteForCategory:
                print("NoSuitableRouteForCategory")
            case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.RouteConfigurationChange:
                print("RouteConfigurationChange")

            }
        }
    }
}

func checkHeadphones() {
    // check NewDeviceAvailable and OldDeviceUnavailable for them being plugged in/unplugged
    let currentRoute = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute
    if currentRoute.outputs.count > 0 {
        for description in currentRoute.outputs {
            if description.portType == AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones {
                print("headphones are plugged in")
                break
            } else {
                print("headphones are unplugged")
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("checking headphones requires a connection to a device")
    }
}


@IBAction
func trim() {
    if self.soundFileURL == nil {
        print("no sound file")
        return
    }

    print("trimming \(soundFileURL!.absoluteString)")
    print("trimming path \(soundFileURL!.lastPathComponent)")
    let asset = AVAsset(URL:self.soundFileURL!)
    exportAsset(asset, fileName: "trimmed.m4a")
}

func exportAsset(asset:AVAsset, fileName:String) {
    let documentsDirectory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    let trimmedSoundFileURL = documentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
    print("saving to \(trimmedSoundFileURL.absoluteString)")



    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(trimmedSoundFileURL.absoluteString) {
        print("sound exists, removing \(trimmedSoundFileURL.absoluteString)")
        do {
            var error:NSError?
            if trimmedSoundFileURL.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(&error) {
                print("is reachable")
            }
            if let e = error {
                print(e.localizedDescription)
            }

            try    NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(trimmedSoundFileURL.absoluteString)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            NSLog("could not remove \(trimmedSoundFileURL)")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }

    if let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A) {
        exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A
        exporter.outputURL = trimmedSoundFileURL

        let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)
        if (duration < 5.0) {
            print("sound is not long enough")
            return
        }
        // e.g. the first 5 seconds
        let startTime = CMTimeMake(0, 1)
        let stopTime = CMTimeMake(5, 1)
        exporter.timeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(startTime, stopTime)

       // do it
        exporter.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({
            switch exporter.status {
            case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed:

                if let e = exporter.error {
                    print("export failed \(e)")
                    switch e.code {
                    case AVError.FileAlreadyExists.rawValue:
                        print("File Exists")
                        break
                    default: break
                    }
                } else {
                    print("export failed")
                }
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Cancelled:
                print("export cancelled \(exporter.error)")
            default:
                print("export complete")
            }
        })
    }

}

@IBAction
func speed() {
    let asset = AVAsset(URL:self.soundFileURL!)
    exportSpeedAsset(asset, fileName: "trimmed.m4a")
}

func exportSpeedAsset(asset:AVAsset, fileName:String) {
    let documentsDirectory =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory,  inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    let trimmedSoundFileURL = documentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)

    let filemanager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if filemanager.fileExistsAtPath(trimmedSoundFileURL.absoluteString)    {
        print("sound exists")
    }

    if let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A) {
        exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A
        exporter.outputURL = trimmedSoundFileURL

        exporter.audioTimePitchAlgorithm = AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmVarispeed




        let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)
        if (duration < 5.0) {
            print("sound is not long enough")
            return
        }

        // do it
        exporter.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({
            switch exporter.status {
            case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed:
                print("export failed \(exporter.error)")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Cancelled:
                print("export cancelled \(exporter.error)")
            default:
                print("export complete")
            }
        })
    }
}


}

// MARK: AVAudioRecorderDelegate
extension RecorderViewController : AVAudioRecorderDelegate {

func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(recorder: AVAudioRecorder,
    successfully flag: Bool) {
        print("finished recording \(flag)")
        stopButton.enabled = false
        playButton.enabled = true
        recordButton.setTitle("Record", forState:.Normal)

        // iOS8 and later
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Recorder",
            message: "Finished Recording",
            preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Keep", style: .Default, handler: {action in
            print("keep was tapped")
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .Default, handler: {action in
            print("delete was tapped")
            self.recorder.deleteRecording()
        }))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated:true, completion:nil)
}

func audioRecorderEncodeErrorDidOccur(recorder: AVAudioRecorder,
    error: NSError?) {

        if let e = error {
            print("\(e.localizedDescription)")
        }
}

}

// MARK: AVAudioPlayerDelegate
extension RecorderViewController : AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    print("finished playing \(flag)")
    recordButton.enabled = true
    stopButton.enabled = false
}

func audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur(player: AVAudioPlayer, error: NSError?) {
    if let e = error {
        print("\(e.localizedDescription)")
    }

}
}
```

Comment: can you check payer != nil?

Comment: @ReinierMelian, that worked! Thanks!

Comment: I will post my answer, to avoid this topic end without answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reviewing your code I think that you should check first if `player` is not nil

something like this

```
@IBAction func slideChange(sender: AnyObject) {
   if(player != nil)
     {
    player.rate = sliderValue.value
     }
}
```

I hope this helps you!